# Executing code before render

Tags: dart

When I load my page, I see the original page (only for a short time) before Dart starts modifying the content. How do I avoid this?

**Example**:

File `index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/dart" src="app.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

File `app.dart`

```
main(){
    var d = new DivElement(); 
    d.text = "This is a test";
    query('body').append(d);
}
```

In this example I would first see a blank page, and then, shortly after, the text "This is a test". I would like only to see the text.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause or not, but the `main` function in Dart is always executed after the DOM is loaded (not sure about the exact timing...).

Comment: That might have something to do with it. If it correspond to the jquery $(document).load(). But are there then some alternative? Or is this just something that we should learn to live with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page will display before the text, because your Dart code will run after the initial render (at least usually). You could apply some white layer on top of the document and remove it when your Dart code is done:

```html
<body>
  <div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: white; z-index: 1000000;"></div>
</body>
```

Then when your Dart code is ready to show the app:

```dart
query('#overlay').remove();
```

Now you will see a blank page until the Dart code is ready to show something.

Answer (score 0):

If you load your JS scripts in the very start of the body, it will be executed before the page loads. So, you would do this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>

    <body>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
        <script type="application/dart" src="app.dart"></script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

That should work. If it doesn't there is probably something going on internally in Dart, which causes this.